# Manually install python for jira lib

Tags: python, cryptography, jira

I have a linux machine in a secure environment and cant download from pypi, so I downloaded python for jira manually and run " pip install --no-index --find-links=jira/ jira".
Getting this error and cant figure out how do solve it.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cryptography;
>   extra == "signedtoken" (from oauthlib[signedtoken]>=1.0.0->jira) (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for cryptography; extra ==
>   "signedtoken" (from oauthlib[signedtoken]>=1.0.0->jira)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add in your *`"--find-links"`* directory a proper cryptography package.
You can download it (on a host with internet connection) from:

[pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#files)

and copy to `jira/jira` directory (on host you are trying to install jira package)

I suggest to use the tar.gz file.

I hope this helps.